# Dynamically store and send SSRS reports as PDF with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a report in SSRS that takes as a parameter a `SalesRepCode` and `Email` to generate a PDF receipt. It's working as it should be if I'm using the Report Viewer.

With C#, I'd like to automatically generate a PDF for each SalesRep that exists, once the PDF is rendered, I'd like to store it on a folder and then send it as an email attachment.

I have looked at the MSDN documentation of the `ReportingService2005` Class, but this refers to the 2005 version, and I'm using SSRS 2012 and I still havent found a thing related to the version I'm using.

Is there a proper way of making this happen?

Comment: Since you are using C#, can't you pull the data into a grid, then from there export out as a PDF using a third party nuget package?  Perhaps something like  PDFSharp.  The only problem I see is that you'd have to format everything from scratch to make it look "pretty" on PDFSharp, but it could work. [link](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=29)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Render`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) method of [ReportExecutionService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.aspx) without any problem. You need to add a service reference to [ReportExecution2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.aspx) which is the [Execution Endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx#Anchor_1) of report server.

**Example**

Below example has been taken from msdn and used by some small changes. To see the original example take a look at [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx#Anchor_2). When using, pay attention to use `PDF` as format and also about the report path it should be the path of your report starting by `/` and ending with report name without `.rdl`.

```
ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
rs.Url = "http://MyServer/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
/* Render arguments */
byte[] result = null;
string reportPath = "/MyFolder/MyReport"; 
string format = "PDF";
string historyID = null;
string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";          
/* Prepare report parameter.*/
ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
parameters[0].Name = "SomeParameter";
parameters[0].Value = "SomeValue";
DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
string showHideToggle = null;
string encoding;
string mimeType;
string extension;
Warning[] warnings = null;
ParameterValue[] reportHistoryParameters = null;
string[] streamIDs = null;
ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();
rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader; 
/*Load and Render Report*/
execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;
result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, 
    out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
/*Save File*/
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\report.pdf", result);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this in Asp.Net Core but its showing some different methods!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the ReportingService2005 Web Service with SQL 2012 and it works fine.

In a nutshell - You add the reference to the Web Service, Bind Params, Call Render() with PDF and save the ByteStream as a local file.

There are confusingly 2 Web Services (Report Service & Report Execution Service)

I think you can get away with just using the Report Execution Service.

First thing to check is that you can see the .asmx file on your SSRS Page
(http://...ReportExecution2005.asmx)

Comment: @Reza Aghaei, did you solved that issue. I face exactly the same issue.