# Unable to find System.Web.Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic MVC web application complete with a Web API that I'm attempting to use to run an existing SSRS report and save those results to a file. I'm following the example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980596/dynamically-store-and-send-ssrs-reports-as-pdf-with-c-sharp) but whenever I attempt to add the line "Using System.Web.Services;" I'm given the following error message: "The type or namespace 'Services' does not exist in the namespace System.Web." Do I need to add something to my project to reference System.Web.Services? I have to have System.Web.Services in order to use the ReportExecutionService.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestAPI.Controllers
{
    public class PrintController : ApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/PrintFile")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage PrintReport()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage returnValue = new 
            HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            if (returnValue.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: do you have the `ReportExecution` referenced?

Comment: "Add Reference" in your MSVS project:  Project > Add Reference > Assemblies, Framework >  and click on System.Web.Services.

Comment: That fixed the System.Web.Services but it's still saying it cannot find ReportExecutionServices. I looked for it in the same spot I found the System.Web.Services reference but nothing came up. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to `System.Web.Services.dll`

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webservice?view=netframework-4.7.2